# How to use generate UITableView for other UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to use a generated `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`.

This is how I am trying to generate:-

## TableViewGeneratorController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewGeneratorController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableView;
    - (UITableView *)getTableView;
@end
```

## TableViewGeneratorController.m

```
#import "TableViewGeneratorController.h"

@interface TableViewGeneratorController (){
}
@end

@implementation TableViewGeneratorController
@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString )nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle )nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self){
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 400)];
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    return self;
}

- (UITableView *)getTableView
{
    return self.tableView;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIndentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Yes";
    return cell;

}

@end
```

Now In my UIViewController I am calling that getTableView and adding the UITableView as subview but I am getting exception:-

## ViewController.m

```
TableViewGeneratorController *tableViewGeneratorController = [[TableViewGeneratorController alloc]init];

UITableView *tableView = [tableViewGeneratorController getTableView];

[self.view addSubview: tableView ];
```

## Exception:-

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo numberOfSectionsInTableView(inlove): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1ba7e0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: how about overriding `-(id)init` method and past all code of initialisation there .. or u just simply call `[[TableViewGeneratorController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` just try this

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** generate any controls in your `init` function. The `init` function is only for logic initialization (like setting a bool to `YES`). Move your table code to `viewDidLoad`.

This will usually throw errors, since the view is not ready yet.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not getting called after this TableViewGeneratorController *tableViewGeneratorController = [[TableViewGeneratorController alloc]init];

Comment: the problem is you only need to create a tableview using your generator when you get the tableview you should set the delegate to the view controller in which you are adding it as a subview.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman I am also thinking like that. but not able to set the delegate to the view controller. Can you please post one answer.

Comment: @KousikChowdhury let me do that for you

Comment: @KousikChowdhury just posted the answer. Please let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

**TableViewGeneratorController.h**

```
@interface TableViewGeneratorController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString )nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle )nibBundleOrNil frame:(CGRect)frame;
- (UITableView *)getTableView;

@end
```

**TableViewGeneratorController.m**

```
@implementation TableViewGeneratorController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString )nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle )nibBundleOrNil frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        _tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableView *)getTableView
{
    return _tableView;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
TableViewGeneratorController *tableViewGeneratorController = [[TableViewGeneratorController alloc] init];
UITableView *tableView = [tableViewGeneratorController getTableView];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Implement table view delegate in ViewController.m

Comment: @KousikChowdhury Where is the actual problem? Can you please explain a little more so that I am able to fix it.

Comment: initTableViewWithFrame is getting called multiple time.If I remove - (void)initTableViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame; then that stopped but got same error. Actually the numberOfRowsInSection is not getting called from ViewController. How to call that>

Comment: @KousikChowdhury sorry my bad. I just edit the post. Please have a look and try again. Instead of `- (void)initTableViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` it should be `- (id)initTableViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

Comment: nope same thing is happening,comming in the initWithNibName block again and again.

Comment: @KousikChowdhury Updated the function in post please try again and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67018/discussion-between-adeel-ur-rehman-and-kousik-chowdhury).

Answer (score 0):

initWithNibName() will never be called if you intialize the tableViewGeneratorController with init()

Comment: BTW initwithnib is getting called and I am getting the tableView  also. but it is failing due to selectionrow. as it is not in the ViewController.